# How to check if a matrix is full rank in DolphinDB？

Tags: matrix, rank, dolphindb

According to the function `ols`: if the independent variable is a matrix, it should be non-singular. So I need to check if it is a full-rank matrix by calculating its rank beforehand. Is there any function in DolphinDB to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function in DolphinDB. But we can provide you with a solution:

Based on the following theorem, you can write the following script to check if a matrix is full rank (for non-square matrix):

[image]

```
det(x.transpose() ** x) != 0
```

You can also use the following user-defined function to calculate the number of non-zero singular values, which is equal to the rank of the matrix.

```
def matrixRank(m){
  return sum 0!=svd(m, computeUV=false);
}
```