# Error "The input matrix is singular" was reported during regression calculation

Tags: regression, dolphindb

When I performed regression calculation as shown in the following script, an error was reported: `The input matrix is singular`.

```
test =select * from tobeols where date =2021.05.31
X=columnNames(test)[3:]
XX=matrix(test[X])

ols(test.RET, XX, 1,2)
```

Here, `X` includes the market value factor ”mv”, one “gtjaAlpha” factor, and industry dummy variables.

When I used the same method for regression analysis on data from other dates, no error was reported. It seems that there is no difference between the data for this day and other dates. Additionally, when the factor "mv" with this date "2021.05.31" was removed, the execution was also successful.  Does anyone know the reason for the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `ols` does not support input of a matrix of non-full rank. Please refer to [How to check if a matrix is full rank in DolphinDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001074/how-to-check-if-a-matrix-is-full-rank-in-dolphindb) to determine whether the `XX` is a full-rank matrix. The function will be improved to handle this type of matrix in the next version.